# Python: How to get StringIO.writelines to accept unicode string?

Tags: python, string, unicode, ascii, stringio

I'm getting a

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 34: ordinal not in range(128)
```

on a string stored in 'a.desc' below as it contains the '£' character.  It's stored in the underlying Google App Engine datastore as a unicode string so that's fine.  The cStringIO.StringIO.writelines function is trying seemingly trying to encode it in ascii format:

```
result.writelines(['blahblah',a.desc,'blahblahblah'])
```

How do I instruct it to treat the encoding as unicode if that's the correct phrasing?

app engine runs on python 2.5

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[StringIO documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html):

> Unlike the memory files implemented by the StringIO module, those provided by [cStringIO] are not able to accept Unicode strings that cannot be encoded as plain ASCII strings.

If possible, use StringIO instead of cStringIO.

Comment: I switched (cStringIO is meant to be better performance-wise) and it didn't throw an error but did print 'Â£' instead of just '£'.

Why is 'Â' showing up now?

Comment: 'Â£' is the Windows-1252 decoding of 0xc2 0xa3 which is the UTF-8 encoding of u'£'. Maybe your terminal, app, or wherever you're seeing that is configured for Windows-1252 instead of UTF-8.

Comment: hmm.  Essentially I'm looking at a web server response through Chrome browser.  Would that be the issue?

Comment: In Chrome you can set the encoding under which the page will be interpreted-- Page menu -> Encoding. Select "Unicode (UTF-8)" and see if that fixes it...

Comment: default is ISO-8859-1 (western).  That should be ok should it not?

Comment: Nope. ISO-8859-1 will behave the same as Windows-1252 in that regard. You probably want to explicitly set the UTF-8 encoding in your page headers so that browsers don't have to guess the encoding. (Unless, of course, something else in your app is already generating output in a non-UTF-8 encoding.)

Answer (score 39):

You can wrap the StringIO object in a `codecs.StreamReaderWriter` object to automatically encode and decode unicode.

Like this:

```
import cStringIO, codecs
buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
codecinfo = codecs.lookup("utf8")
wrapper = codecs.StreamReaderWriter(buffer, 
        codecinfo.streamreader, codecinfo.streamwriter)

wrapper.writelines([u"list of", u"unicode strings"])
```

`buffer` will be filled with utf-8 encoded bytes.

If I understand your case correctly, you will only need to write, so you could also do:

```
import cStringIO, codecs
buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
wrapper = codecs.getwriter("utf8")(buffer)
```

Comment: Also, the file-like object returned by `cStringIO.StringIO()` doesn't work in the `with` statement, but the wrapper returned by `codecs.StreamReaderWriter()` does!

Comment: This sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/45101658/562769 - do you know the answer to my question?

Answer (score 4):

You can also encode your string as utf-8 manually before adding it to the StringIO

```
for val in rows:
    if isinstance(val, unicode):
        val = val.encode('utf-8')
result.writelines(rows)
```

Comment: use `isinstance` instead of `type is X`

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.6 introduced the `io` module and you should consider using [`io.StringIO()`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/io.html#io.StringIO), "An in-memory stream for unicode text."

In older python versions this is not optimized (pure Python), in later versions this has been optimized to (fast) C code.