# Capture stdout from a script?

Tags: python, stdout, sys

suppose there is a script doing something like this:

```
# module writer.py
import sys

def write():
    sys.stdout.write("foobar")
```

Now suppose I want to capture the output of the `write` function and store it in a variable for further processing. The naive solution was:

```
# module mymodule.py
from writer import write

out = write()
print out.upper()
```

But this doesn't work. I come up with another solution and it works, but please, let me know if there is a better way to solve the problem. Thanks

```
import sys
from cStringIO import StringIO

# setup the environment
backup = sys.stdout

# ####
sys.stdout = StringIO()     # capture output
write()
out = sys.stdout.getvalue() # release output
# ####

sys.stdout.close()  # close the stream 
sys.stdout = backup # restore original stdout

print out.upper()   # post processing
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Setting `stdout` is a reasonable way to do it.  Another is to run it as another process:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-c", "import writer; writer.write()"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = proc.communicate()[0]
print out.upper()
```

Comment: check_output directly captures the output of a command run in a subprocess:  <br>
    value = subprocess.check_output( command, shell=True)

Comment: On modern Python versions you can do `capture_output=True` instead of `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`.

Answer (score 90):

On **Python 3.4**+, use the [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) context manager:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io

f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    help(pow)
s = f.getvalue()
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem when trying to write to sys.stdout.buffer (as you need to do when writing bytes). StringIO does not have the buffer attribute, while TextIOWrapper does. See the answer from @JonnyJD.

Answer (score 52):

Here is a context manager version of your code.  It yields a list of two values; the first is stdout, the second is stderr.

```
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def capture():
    import sys
    from cStringIO import StringIO
    oldout,olderr = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
    try:
        out=[StringIO(), StringIO()]
        sys.stdout,sys.stderr = out
        yield out
    finally:
        sys.stdout,sys.stderr = oldout, olderr
        out[0] = out[0].getvalue()
        out[1] = out[1].getvalue()

with capture() as out:
    print 'hi'
```

Comment: Love this solution.  I modified, so as not to accidentally lose stuff from a stream on which I'm not expecting output, e.g. unexpected errors.  In my case, capture() can accept sys.stderr or sys.stdout as a parameter, indicating to only capture that stream.

Comment: StringIO doesn't support unicode in any fashion, so you can integrate the answer here to make the above support non-ASCII chars: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1819009/425050

Comment: Modifying a yielded value in the finally is really rather wierd - `with capture() as out:` will behave differently to `with capture() as out, err:`

Comment: Unicode / stdout.buffer support can be reached with using the io module. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19344871/1904815).

Comment: This solution breaks if you use `subprocess` and redirect output to sys.stdout/stderr. This is because `StringIO` is not a real file object and misses the `fileno()` function.

Answer (score 21):

Starting with Python 3 you can also use `sys.stdout.buffer.write()` to write (already) encoded byte strings to stdout (see [stdout in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/sys.html#sys.stdout)).
When you do that, the simple `StringIO` approach doesn't work because neither `sys.stdout.encoding` nor `sys.stdout.buffer` would be available.

Starting with Python 2.6 you can use the [`TextIOBase` API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase), which includes the missing attributes:

```
import sys
from io import TextIOWrapper, BytesIO

# setup the environment
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = TextIOWrapper(BytesIO(), sys.stdout.encoding)

# do some writing (indirectly)
write("blub")

# get output
sys.stdout.seek(0)      # jump to the start
out = sys.stdout.read() # read output

# restore stdout
sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout = old_stdout

# do stuff with the output
print(out.upper())
```

This solution works for Python 2 >= 2.6 and Python 3.
Please note that our `sys.stdout.write()` only accepts unicode strings and `sys.stdout.buffer.write()` only accepts byte strings.
This might not be the case for old code, but is often the case for code that is built to run on Python 2 and 3 without changes.

If you need to support code that sends byte strings to stdout directly without using stdout.buffer, you can use this variation:

```
class StdoutBuffer(TextIOWrapper):
    def write(self, string):
        try:
            return super(StdoutBuffer, self).write(string)
        except TypeError:
            # redirect encoded byte strings directly to buffer
            return super(StdoutBuffer, self).buffer.write(string)
```

You don't have to set the encoding of the buffer the sys.stdout.encoding, but this helps when using this method for testing/comparing script output.

Answer (score 13):

Or maybe use functionality that is already there...

```
from IPython.utils.capture import capture_output

with capture_output() as c:
    print('some output')

c()

print c.stdout
```

Answer (score 10):

This is the decorator counterpart of my original code.

`writer.py` remains the same:

```
import sys

def write():
    sys.stdout.write("foobar")
```

`mymodule.py` sligthly gets modified:

```
from writer import write as _write
from decorators import capture

@capture
def write():
    return _write()

out = write()
# out post processing...
```

And here is the decorator:

```
def capture(f):
    """
    Decorator to capture standard output
    """
    def captured(*args, **kwargs):
        import sys
        from cStringIO import StringIO

        # setup the environment
        backup = sys.stdout

        try:
            sys.stdout = StringIO()     # capture output
            f(*args, **kwargs)
            out = sys.stdout.getvalue() # release output
        finally:
            sys.stdout.close()  # close the stream 
            sys.stdout = backup # restore original stdout

        return out # captured output wrapped in a string

    return captured
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a context manager taking inspiration from @JonnyJD's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19344871) supporting writing bytes to `buffer` attributes abut also taking advantage of [sys's dunder-io referenes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__) for further simplification.

```py
import io
import sys
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def capture_output():
    output = {}
    try:
        # Redirect
        sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BytesIO(), sys.stdout.encoding)
        sys.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BytesIO(), sys.stderr.encoding)
        yield output
    finally:
        # Read
        sys.stdout.seek(0)
        sys.stderr.seek(0)
        output['stdout'] = sys.stdout.read()
        output['stderr'] = sys.stderr.read()
        sys.stdout.close()
        sys.stderr.close()

        # Restore
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__


with capture_output() as output:
    print('foo')
    sys.stderr.buffer.write(b'bar')

print('stdout: {stdout}'.format(stdout=output['stdout']))
print('stderr: {stderr}'.format(stderr=output['stderr']))
```

Output is:

```
stdout: foo

stderr: bar
```

Answer (score 5):

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-do-i-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file-in-python) (the example of how to redirect output, not the `tee` part) uses `os.dup2` to redirect a stream at the OS level.  That is nice because it will apply to commands that you spawn from your program as well.

Answer (score 4):

I think You should look at these four objects:

```
from test.test_support import captured_stdout, captured_output, \
    captured_stderr, captured_stdin
```

Example:

```
from writer import write

with captured_stdout() as stdout:
    write()
print stdout.getvalue().upper()
```

UPD: As Eric said in a comment, one shouldn't use they directly, so I copied and pasted it.

```
# Code from test.test_support:
import contextlib
import sys

@contextlib.contextmanager
def captured_output(stream_name):
    """Return a context manager used by captured_stdout and captured_stdin
    that temporarily replaces the sys stream *stream_name* with a StringIO."""
    import StringIO
    orig_stdout = getattr(sys, stream_name)
    setattr(sys, stream_name, StringIO.StringIO())
    try:
        yield getattr(sys, stream_name)
    finally:
        setattr(sys, stream_name, orig_stdout)

def captured_stdout():
    """Capture the output of sys.stdout:

       with captured_stdout() as s:
           print "hello"
       self.assertEqual(s.getvalue(), "hello")
    """
    return captured_output("stdout")

def captured_stderr():
    return captured_output("stderr")

def captured_stdin():
    return captured_output("stdin")
```

Answer (score 4):

I like the contextmanager solution however if you need the buffer stored with the open file and fileno support you could do something like this.

```
import six
from six.moves import StringIO


class FileWriteStore(object):
    def __init__(self, file_):
        self.__file__ = file_
        self.__buff__ = StringIO()

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in {
            "write", "writelines", "get_file_value", "__file__",
                "__buff__"}:
            return super(FileWriteStore, self).__getattribute__(name)
        return self.__file__.__getattribute__(name)

    def write(self, text):
        if isinstance(text, six.string_types):
            try:
                self.__buff__.write(text)
            except:
                pass
        self.__file__.write(text)

    def writelines(self, lines):
        try:
            self.__buff__.writelines(lines)
        except:
            pass
        self.__file__.writelines(lines)

    def get_file_value(self):
        return self.__buff__.getvalue()
```

use

```
import sys
sys.stdout = FileWriteStore(sys.stdout)
print "test"
buffer = sys.stdout.get_file_value()
# you don't want to print the buffer while still storing
# else it will double in size every print
sys.stdout = sys.stdout.__file__
print buffer
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way when third party code has already copied a reference to `sys.stdout` is to temporarily replace the `write()` method itself:

```
from types import MethodType
...
f = io.StringIO()
def new_write(self, data):
    f.write(data)

old_write = sys.stdout.write
sys.stdout.write = MethodType(new_write, sys.stdout)
error = command.run(args)
sys.stdout.write = old_write
output = f.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought that @arthur's comment should exist in an answer.
Using the `check_output` method from `subprocess` seems easiest:

```py
In [1]: import subprocess
   ...: 
   ...: command = "echo 'hello world'"
   ...: output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, encoding='utf-8')

In [2]: print(output)
hello world
```