# How to test print statements?

Tags: python, unit-testing, stdout

You want to write `unittest`-cases for a function like that:

```
def test_me(a):
    for b in c:
        print do_something(a,b)
```

At first I thought about just collecting the outputs of `do_something` in a string and then returning it, to print and test the whole output together. But it's not always convinient because such loops could cause your buffer string to get very big, depending on the circumstances. So what can you do to test the output, when it is printed and not returned?

Comment: This help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136611/capture-stdout-from-a-script-in-python

Comment: @both comments above: I don't know what is a typical approach for unittesting, both might be possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`print`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) prints to [`sys.stdout`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdout), which you can reassign to your own object if you wish. The only thing your object needs is a `write` function which takes a single string argument.

Since Python 2.6 you may also change `print` to be a function rather than a language construct by adding `from __future__ import print_function` to the top of your script. This way you can override `print` with your own function.

Answer (score 8):

In Python 3 it's easy to use `unittest.mock` on the builtin `print` function:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, call

@patch('builtins.print')
def test_print(mocked_print):
    print('foo')
    print()

    assert mocked_print.mock_calls == [call('foo'), call()]
```

Comment: Same thing, other syntax: `with unittest.mock.patch('builtins.print') as mocked_print:`