# Mock Python's built in print function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-2.x

I've tried

```
from mock import Mock
import __builtin__

__builtin__.print = Mock()
```

But that raises a syntax error. I've also tried patching it like so

```
@patch('__builtin__.print')
def test_something_that_performs_lots_of_prints(self, mock_print):

    # assert stuff
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.3, though would be interested to hear about how to do it under 3, if it's not possible under 2.7.x

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122582/how-to-test-print-statements

Comment: Yeah, mocking sys.stdout is probably the best way to do this in a testing situation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`print` is a keyword in python 2.x, using it as attribute raises a SyntaxError. You can avoid that by using `from __future__ import print_function` in the beginning of the file.

Note: you can't simply use `setattr`, because the print function you modified doesn't get invoked unless the `print` statement is disabled.

Edit: you also need to `from __future__ import print_function` in every file you want your modified `print` function to be used, or it will be masked by the `print` statement.

Comment: So I could `setattr(__builtin__, 'print', Mock())` and then disable the print statement somehow? Or do you mean disable it by importing the Python 3 print function? It would be nice to be able to do this entirely on the test side without modifying the code under test.

Comment: @aychedee In all the source files that need to use your modified `print` function, you need to disable it by importing the Python 3 `print` function. `setattr` used in lqc's way will not work because it's masked by the `print` statement.

Comment: Okay, cheers, thanks xiaomao. That works. So the answer is that this is only possible by using the Python 3 print function, and without that it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please provide a full example how to test the actual call to `print`?

Answer (score 55):

I know that there is already an accepted answer but there is simpler solution for that problem - mocking the print in python 2.x. Answer is in the mock library tutorial: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html and it is:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> def foo():
...     print 'Something'
...
>>> @patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO)
... def test(mock_stdout):
...     foo()
...     assert mock_stdout.getvalue() == 'Something\n'
...
>>> test()
```

Of course you can use also following assertion:

```
self.assertEqual("Something\n", mock_stdout.getvalue())
```

I have checked this solution in my unittests and it is working as expected. Hope this helps somebody. Cheers!

Comment: This doesn't work for for `pytest` in Python 2 (sorry for the formatting in comments). "def test_status(mocker):
        mocker_print = mocker.patch("sys.stdout", new_callable=StringIO)
>       print("yes")
E       TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'"

Comment: As of Python 3, you need to import StringIO from io like so: `from io import StringIO`.

Answer (score 45):

This is a much simpler Python 3 solution -- it's easier to use `unittest.mock` directly on the builtin `print` function, rather than fiddling around with `sys.stdout`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, call

@patch('builtins.print')
def test_print(mocked_print):
    print('foo')
    print()

    assert mocked_print.mock_calls == [call('foo'), call()]
```

Alternative example, evaluating `args` and `kwargs` directly:

```
@patch('builtins.print')
def test_print(mocked_print):
    print('foo', 'bar', file=sys.stderr)

    assert mocked_print.call_args.args == ('foo', 'bar')
    assert mocked_print.call_args.kwargs == dict(file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: This is the only way that makes sense for Python 3. This way we can perform assertions on mocks which is a major advantage for testing.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, which is what I ended up using. However I noticed that it's far better to limit the patch to the context where I expect print to be used (the module it's imported in), otherwise I'll be patching the builtin that pytest, pdb, etcetera use as well -- for example that prevented me from breaking into the test code. So assuming the call is in module `myapp.mymod`, I'd patch `myapp.mymod.print` instead.

Comment: How do you check a call to print() that supplies argument file=sys.stderr?

Comment: `printed = '\n'.join(x.args[0] for x in mocked_print.mocks_calls)` if you would like to recreate what was printed (assuming you only pass one arg at a time to print, cause you probably use f-strings.

Answer (score 6):

```
from unittest.mock import patch


def greet():
    print("Hello World")


@patch('builtins.print')
def test_greet(mock_print):
    greet()
    mock_print.assert_called_with("Hello World!")
```

Comment: It looks like this solution was already proposed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50740647/6682517).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with the `print` statement from 2.x as opposed to the `print()` function from 2.x, you could mock your `sys.stdout` instead.

Write a dummy "file", perhaps in about this way:

```
class Writable(object):
    """Class which has the capability to replace stdout."""
    newwrite = None
    def __init__(self, oldstdout, newwrite=None):
        self.oldstdout = oldstdout
        if newwrite is not None:
            self.newwrite = newwrite
    def write(self, data):
        self.newwrite(self.oldstdout, data)
    @classmethod
    def subclass(cls, writefunc):
        newcls = type('', (cls,),
            dict(write=lambda self, data: writefunc(self.oldstdout, data)
        return newcls
```

This class expects to be combined with a writing function which gets the printed data. This writing function is supposed to take 2 arguments: the first one with the "old stdout" to be used for printing at the end, and a further one for the data.

Let's take

```
def mywrite(sink, data):
    sink.write(data.encode("hex"))
```

for that.

Now you can do

```
import sys
sys.stdout = Writable(sys.stdout, mywrite)
```

or you can do

```
@Writable.subclass
def mywritable(sink, data)
    sink.write(data.encode("hex"))

sys.stdout = mywritable(sys.stdout)
```

The 2nd version is a bit trickier: it creates a subclass of the `Writable` with the help of a decorator function which turns the given function into a method of the new class created instead and put into the name where the given function comes from.

After that, you have a new class which can be instantiated with the "old stdout" as argument and can replace `sys.stdout` after that.

Answer (score 3):

My version.

In the tested program(ex: `pp.py`):

```
from __future__ import print_function

def my_func():
    print('hello')
```

In the test program:

```
def test_print(self):
    from pp import my_func
    from mock import call
    with mock.patch('__builtin__.print') as mock_print:
       my_func()
       mock_print.assert_has_calls(
            [
                call('hello')
            ]
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import mock
import sys

mock_stdout = mock.Mock()
sys.stdout = mock_stdout
print 'Hello!'
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

print mock_stdout.mock_calls
[call.write('Hello!'), call.write('\n')]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what you did here and why the code in the question didn't work.

Comment: We are switching sys.stdout by our mock object, and when we print some text, it may be found in mock_stdout calls.
At the end we returns sys.stdout to original state.

Answer (score 1):

This is a v3 version of @KC's answer.

I didn't want to mock print because I specifically wanted to see the output as a whole, not check out individual calls so StringIO makes more sense to me.

```
from io import StringIO
from unittest.mock import patch

def foo():
    print ('Something')

def test():
    with patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO) as buffer:
        foo()
    fake_stdout = buffer.getvalue()

    #print() is back!
    print(f"fake_stdout:{fake_stdout}")
    assert fake_stdout == 'Something\n'

test()
```

#### warning:

for the duration of the patch, mocking stdout plays badly with using `pdb.set_trace()`.  I commented out `with...`, added `if True:` to keep the indentation, debugged my script and put back the batch once I fixed my error.

```
    #with patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO) as buffer:
    if True:
        foo()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the module is called `__builtins__` and you don't need to import it.

Now, in Python 2 `print` is a keyword so you can't use it as an attribute name directly. You can use `setattr`/`getattr` to workaround it:

```
getattr(__builtins__, "print")
```

Another option is to use `from __future__ import print_function` which changes how Python parses the module to Python 3 syntax.

Comment: `__builtin__ == __builtins__   >>> True` in 2.7.3. So without using the Python 3 print function the answer is no?

Answer (score 0):

As lcq says, **print** is a keyword.  So, think about what it would mean if you were actually successful in patching/mocking print under Python 2.7.3.  You would have code like this:

```
print "Hi."
```

turning into:

```
<MagicMock id='49489360'> "Hi."
```

MagicMock objects cannot be accessed this way, so you would get a syntax error.

So... Yeah.  You can only mock the Python3 print *function* or sys.stdout.

Answer (score 0):

This Python 3 example builds upon the Python 2 answer by Krzysztof. It uses `unittest.mock`. It uses a reusable helper method for making the assertion.

```
import io
import unittest
import unittest.mock

from .solution import fizzbuzz


class TestFizzBuzz(unittest.TestCase):

    @unittest.mock.patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=io.StringIO)
    def assert_stdout(self, n, expected_output, mock_stdout):
        fizzbuzz(n)
        self.assertEqual(mock_stdout.getvalue(), expected_output)

    def test_only_numbers(self):
        self.assert_stdout(2, '1\n2\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also used `assert_any_call`

```
from unittest.mock import patch, call

@patch('builtins.print')
def test_print(mocked_print):
    print('foo')
    print()

   mocked_print.assert_any_call('foo')
```