# Suppress Output in Tested Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-unittest

I would like to suppress output using `print` from a tested function, while keeping output from the testing function, using a decorator on the testing function, in a safe manner. Essentially:

```
script.py

def func():
    print("script")
```

This module is called in:

```
test_script.py

import script

@some_decorator
def test_func():
    print("test_script")
    script.func()

test_func()
```

What should `some_decorator` be, for `test_script` to print without `script`? I can import any library as necessary on either of the scripts, preferably from the standard library.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm using `importlib` to import `script.py`, so the import line should be something like this:

```
import importlib
file_name = "script"
script = importlib.import_module(file_name)
```

Comment: You'll have to write it yourself, there's nothing in the standard library.

Comment: The clean - and recommended - way to achieve this is to use the `logging` package in place of "print"ing. The standard documentation provides a tutorial with plenty of examples.

Comment: Here is what you need, so it's possible duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998908/is-it-possible-to-mock-pythons-built-in-print-function

Comment: @Sergius Here you want to mock `print` in the SUT but not in the test itself, which I guess will be tricky.