# How to test a function that takes user input then calls other functions based on the user input?

Tags: python, python-unittest

This is the function that I have and it takes user input then further calls other functions depending on the input.

I should test whether the input is one of those 2 characters a or b.

```
def display_menu() -> str:
    """
    Start menu that directs the user wether
    a new or existing option is chosen
    """
    clrscr()
    program_title()
    print("Hello and Welcome are you: \n")
    status = input("a)New User\nb)Exsisting user \n")
    while status not in ("a", "b"):
        print(Fore.RED + "Please choose between a or b")
        status = input("a)New User\nb)Existing user \n")
    if status == "a":
        new_user()
    elif status == "b":
        exsisting_user()

    return status
```

And this is what I got so far

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from validate import display_menu,new_user

class TestValidate(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    testing  for user input   
    between two options offered
    """
    def test_a(self):
        input = __builtins__.input
         __builtins__.input = lambda _: 'a'
        self.assertTrue('please enter your username')
```

Comment: Try looking at [How To Use unittest to Write a Test Case for a Function in Python](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-unittest-to-write-a-test-case-for-a-function-in-python).

Comment: Also see [Using unittest.mock to patch input() in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18161330/2745495) on how to properly mock/patch the builtin `input`.

Comment: The more I read less I know.still didn't find an answer.but thnx

Answer (score 1):

If the goal of the tests is to check that passing `a` calls `new_user()`, passing `b` calls `existing_user()`, and passing neither one results in an infinite loop until the user passes the correct one, then you can write tests that:

1. Patches the `input` function to *simulate* user input (`a`, `b`, and some invalid inputs for error cases) but not really requiring user inputs (since the goal of writing unit tests is to have automated tests)
2. Patches the `new_user()` and `existing_user()` functions to *not* call the actual functions, but only intercept and check that they were actually called

(My answer here will ignore `clrscr()`, `program_title()`, the `print`-ing of `"Hello and Welcome are you: \n"`, and the `colorama` `Fore.Red` outputs, as that's irrelevant to the `input` `a` and `b`, which, as I understand it, is what your question is all about.)

##### Patching the `input` function

Your attempt

```py
input = __builtins__.input
__builtins__.input = lambda _: 'a'
```

kind of works, but that's not the correct way since that directly or permanently replaces the built-in `input` function. Your tests would need to remember to "un-patch" it so that it doesn't affect the other tests. Patching something should ideally only be done as part of the **test scope**, and should not "leak" into other tests.

From the [unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html):

> ...mock provides a `patch()` decorator that handles patching module and class level attributes within the scope of a test...
>
> [`patch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) acts as a function decorator, class decorator or a context manager. Inside the body of the function or `with` statement, the *target* is patched with a *new* object. When the function/with statement exits the patch is undone.

...and that's how the answers in [Using unittest.mock to patch input() in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18161330/2745495) describe how to do it: use [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch). Following those answers, patch the `input` call to return either `a` or `b`, call `display_menu()`, then assert that `display_menu`'s return value matches the simulated input:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from validate import display_menu

class TestValidate(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("builtins.input", return_value="a")
    def test_a(self, patched_input):
        status = display_menu()
        self.assertEqual(status, "a")

    @patch("builtins.input", return_value="b")
    def test_b(self, patched_input):
        status = display_menu()
        self.assertEqual(status, "b")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

```
$ python -m unittest -v tests/test_validate.py
test_a (tests.test_validate.TestValidate) ... ok
test_b (tests.test_validate.TestValidate) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

##### Patching the `new_user()`/`existing_user()` functions

Next, you want to know if `display_menu` calls the right functions based on the input. You can use [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) again on those, which returns a [`MagicMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock) object. One of the methods of a `MagicMock` is [`assert_called`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called) which

> Assert that the mock was called at least once

(There are other varieties of `assert_*`, such as for checking how many times the mock was called and how it was called.)

So, assuming both methods are defined in the same `validate.py` module (`validate.new_user`, `validate.existing_user`), same as what you did for `input`, patch them like so:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from validate import display_menu

class TestValidate(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("validate.new_user")
    @patch("builtins.input", return_value="a")
    def test_a(self, patched_input, patched_new_user):
        status = display_menu()

        self.assertEqual(status, "a")
        patched_new_user.assert_called()

    @patch("validate.existing_user")
    @patch("builtins.input", return_value="b")
    def test_b(self, patched_input, patched_existing_user):
        status = display_menu()

        self.assertEqual(status, "b")
        patched_existing_user.assert_called()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

```
$ python -m unittest -v tests/test_validate.py
test_a (tests.test_validate.TestValidate) ... ok
test_b (tests.test_validate.TestValidate) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

(If they are not defined in the same `validate.py` file, then adjust the test accordingly, specifically the `patch("validate.existing_user")` part which says "*patch 'existing_user' from package/module 'validate*".)

If you want to be doubly certain that when `new_user` is called, `existing_user` isn't (and vice-versa), simply patch both in the tests and assert accordingly:

```
class TestValidate(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("validate.existing_user")
    @patch("validate.new_user")
    @patch("builtins.input", return_value="a")
    def test_a(self, patched_input, patched_new_user, patched_existing_user):
        status = display_menu()

        self.assertEqual(status, "a")
        patched_new_user.assert_called()
        patched_existing_user.assert_not_called()

    @patch("validate.existing_user")
    @patch("validate.new_user")
    @patch("builtins.input", return_value="b")
    def test_b(self, patched_input, patched_new_user, patched_existing_user):
        status = display_menu()

        self.assertEqual(status, "b")
        patched_new_user.assert_not_called()
        patched_existing_user.assert_called()
```

##### Patching for incorrect input

The trickiest part to test here is the `while` loop to handle invalid inputs. Same as before, you need to `patch` the built-in input, but patch it in a way that it simulates repeated/multiple invalid user inputs (ex. `x`, `y`, `z`) and then ends with either an `a` or a `b`, in which case it should end up calling either `new_user` or `existing_user`.

This is done by `patch`-ing `input` with a `MagicMock` with a [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect):

> Using `side_effect` to return a sequence of values:
>
> ```
> >>> mock = Mock()
> >>> mock.side_effect = [3, 2, 1]
> >>> mock(), mock(), mock()
> (3, 2, 1)
> ```

Like so:

```
class TestValidate(unittest.TestCase):
    ...

    @patch("validate.existing_user")
    @patch("validate.new_user")
    @patch("builtins.input", side_effect=["x", "y", "z", "a"])
    def test_invalid(self, patched_input, patched_new_user, patched_existing_user):
        status = display_menu()

        self.assertEqual(status, "a")
        patched_new_user.assert_called_once()
        patched_existing_user.assert_not_called()
```

```
$ python -m unittest -v tests/test_validate.py
...
test_invalid (tests.test_validate.TestValidate) ... Please choose between a or b
Please choose between a or b
Please choose between a or b
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.003s

OK
```

Notice from the test logs that it prints out the message from the `while` loop 3 times. That doesn't look good, so, if you want, same as what's done for `input` [you can also patch the built-in `print` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12998908/2745495):

```
class TestValidate(unittest.TestCase):
    ...

    @patch("validate.existing_user")
    @patch("validate.new_user")
    @patch("builtins.input", side_effect=["x", "y", "z", "a"]))
    @patch("builtins.print", autospec=True)
    def test_invalid(self, patched_print, patched_input, patched_new_user, patched_existing_user):
        status = display_menu()

        self.assertEqual(status, "a")

        # Expect to run the code inside the loop 3 times
        self.assertEqual(patched_print.call_count, 3)

        # Expect that the last user input `a` calls `new_user`
        patched_new_user.assert_called_once()
        patched_existing_user.assert_not_called()
```

```
$ python -m unittest -v tests/test_validate.py
test_a (tests.test_validate.TestValidate) ... ok
test_b (tests.test_validate.TestValidate) ... ok
test_invalid (tests.test_validate.TestValidate) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.006s

OK
```

I highly recommend reading through the [unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#) to get familiar with all the functionalities it can provide.

Comment: Thank you Gino. this seems much clearer now i will certainly got trough the docs cause i got so much to learn, now i got some base to work with.

Comment: tests are running fine except the first one where im assertingEqual that status(function display_menu()) when input is "a" is equal to "a" im getting infinite printing of new_user function where im asking for username input first and it goes `    while True:
        username = input("Please enter your username: \n ")
        if not re.match(r'^[a-zA-z0-9]{2,12}$', username):
            print(
                    Fore.RED + 'userame must be 2 to 12 characters long\
 and contain letters and numbers')
            continue
        break` im getting that print infinite?

Comment: So basicaly i dont need those 2 functions to do anything( new_user and existing user)  since i will be testing only if certain input is calling certain function and maybe like you said that calls one function only( so when one is called other one id not) cause now in first test right func is called but it throws infinite string like input in in called function from the patched input is invalid) if i leave those 2 functions to do nothing first test should be ok.