# Python StringIO is not correctly capturing data from stderr

Tags: python, unit-testing, stderr, stringio

I have written some unittests that analyze data that is logged with the standard python logging function. Using some of the ideas that I found here: [Capture stdout from a script in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136611/capture-stdout-from-a-script-in-python) about how to capture data from stderr, I have come up with the following script, which I have simplified down to the bare minimum to illustrate a problem that I have encountered. (the loop below is simulates the fact that this function might be called from various unittests)

```
import logging, sys
from StringIO import StringIO

def get_stderr():
    saved_stderr = sys.stderr

    stderr_string_io = StringIO()
    sys.stderr = stderr_string_io
    try:
        logging.error("Foobar!!!")

    finally:
        # set the stdout and stderr back to their original values
        sys.stderr = saved_stderr

    err_output = stderr_string_io.getvalue()
    return err_output

for x in [1, 2]:
    err_output = get_stderr()
    print  "Run %d: %s" % (x, err_output)
```

If you run the script it will give the following output, in which the logging output from the second loop iteration is totally lost:

```
Run 1: ERROR:root:Foobar!!!
Run 2: 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

While I would expect it to give the following output:

```
Run 1: ERROR:root:Foobar!!!
Run 2: ERROR:root:Foobar!!!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Note: that executing `stderr_string_io.close()` at the end of the function does not work, as the script then throws an `ValueError` the next time the function is executed.

Why does this code not behave as expected, and what is the solution to correct this problem?

Comment: This is odd behaviour indeed. If you put a `logging.error("practicing")` at the top of the file, everything works... but ignores you replacing `stderr`.

Comment: Yes, that is very strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
logging.error
```

it runs

```
def error(msg, *args, **kwargs):
    if len(root.handlers) == 0:
        basicConfig()
    root.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

Since there are no root handlers at the start, it runs `basicConfig` with no arguments, which does:

```
def basicConfig():
    _acquireLock()
    try:
        if len(root.handlers) == 0:
            h = StreamHandler(None)
            handlers = [h]
            dfs = None
            style = '%'
            fs = kwargs.get("format", _STYLES[style][1])
            fmt = Formatter(fs, dfs, style)
            for h in handlers:
                if h.formatter is None:
                    h.setFormatter(fmt)
                root.addHandler(h)
    finally:
        _releaseLock()
```

I've removed code that can't run when you have no arguments.

So this has set `handlers = [StreamHandler(None)]`:

```
class StreamHandler(Handler):
    def __init__(self, stream=None):
        Handler.__init__(self)
        if stream is None:
            stream = sys.stderr
        self.stream = stream
```

which means that you have the top level logger permanantly attached to whatever was `stdout` at the time you called it.

This causes your problem, because you throw away that output. This means that the output will go to a dead StringIO object, and be lost.

One way to deal with this is to go through `handlers` when updating `stderr` and also replace anything that refers to `stderr`:

```
import logging, sys
from StringIO import StringIO

def get_stderr():
    saved_stderr = sys.stderr
    stderr_string_io = StringIO()

    for handler in logging.root.handlers:
        if handler.stream is sys.stderr:
            handler.stream = stderr_string_io

    sys.stderr = stderr_string_io

    try:
        logging.error("Foobar!!!")

    finally:
        # set the stdout and stderr back to their original values
        for handler in logging.root.handlers:
            if handler.stream is sys.stderr:
                handler.stream = saved_stderr

        sys.stderr = saved_stderr

    err_output = stderr_string_io.getvalue()
    return err_output

for x in [1, 2]:
    err_output = get_stderr()
    print  "Run %d: %s" % (x, err_output)
```

I don't know how well this will work. It also won't catch any loggers that aren't root loggers. Personally the idea of capturing `sys.stdout` by value is absurd, and this seems like an inevitable result.

Comment: I agree that you would not normally want to capture the sys.stdout and sys.stderr, however in this particular case I am writing a unit-test for error handling code that writes to stderr. The unittest must analyze that the the correct logs are being written for different error conditions.

Comment: @AlexanderMarquardt I'm not referring to *you*, I'm saying that `logging` is the one being absurd!

Comment: In the end I decided to go with a different approach for capturing the logs. Python has some decent mock and patch functionality for unit testing that allows you to override the default logging functionality without having to mess around with stdio/stderr.