# Execute command set results as variable

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me how to set the output of a command to a variable?

Basically, I'm looking for the Python equivalent to this bash example:

```
blah="ajsdlk akajl <ajksd@ajksldf.com>"
blah=$(echo "$blah" | cut -d '<' -f 2 | cut -d '>' -f 1)
echo "$blah"
ajksd@ajksldf.com
```

Comment: You can use subprocess. This looks very close to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture stdout from a script in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136611/capture-stdout-from-a-script-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `string.split`

```
>>> blah="ajsdlk akajl <ajksd@ajksldf.com>"
>>> blah.split('<')[1].split('>')[0]
'ajksd@ajksldf.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

If a function returns a string, just capture its return value. If you're looking to capture the standard output from a function, wrap it with a `StringIO` wrapper.