# How to check for global variables in source code using awk, sed or grep?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I need to run a series of `Python` source codes against a bash script that contains logic to check for the presence of global variables. There are 2 criteria that I could use to see if a variable is global:

```
read file line by line
if there is an '=' (assignment sign) in the line AND no '#' in beginning of line (it is not commented out), check:
    is there a 'def' string anywhere in the text above this assignment line, e.g. def function_name()?
         if yes, variable within a function and hence not global
         else, possible global variable
```

How do I do implement this pseudo code using `grep`, `awk`, or `sed`? I am also open to suggestions regarding better strategies of finding global variables with the bash script.

Example code:

```
int a = 23

def func_name():
    ...body...
```

This code fails our test.

Example code 2:

```
def function_name():
    int a = 4
    ...
```

This code passes the test.

Comment: Added 2 examples to make the question more specific.

Comment: Using line-oriented tools to analyze Python source code seems extremely misdirected when there are good Python source code analyzers written in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160744/detect-all-global-variables-within-a-python-function

Comment: Implementing this pseudocode as stated, is trivial: You need a flip-flop which is initially false, is set to true once you encounter a `def`, and set to false again when you encounter the end of the function. Whenever you see an `=` and the flip-flop is false, you consider it as global variable. The real problem, of course, is already in the Pseudo code: It will occasionally report a correct global, but will also give false positives and miss some globals.

Comment: It is interesting to consider this type of thing without using python, but that's also unwise if you're actually parsing known-safe python code on a system that actually has python installed.  If you don't want to run the code (perhaps you found it online?) and/or don't have python installed locally, perhaps this is an interesting premise.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is a good idea, but here is an literal implementation of your logic:

```sh
awk -F= '
  /^[^#]/ && NF > 1 && saw_def { print "not global:", $0; next  }
  NF > 1 { print "possibly global:", $0 }
  { saw_def = /def/ }
' file.py
```

This tells awk to use `=` as a field separator on four `pattern {action}` pairs:

1. Line starts with non-`#`, has a 2nd field (thus has a `=`), and the `saw_def` variable is set:
   Print the line as not a global assignment; move on to next line (stop pattern matching)
2. Line otherwise has a `=`:
   Print the line as possibly a global assignment
3. (Any line not matched by #1):
   Set `saw_def` to a boolean representing whether "def" exists on the line

Here is an example that will fail your test:

```py
def function_name():
    int a = 4
    int b = 8
```

The logic you requested will note that `a` is not global and that `b` is possibly global.

---

This should be better:

```
awk '
  NF == 0 { next }
  {
    indent = match ($0, /[^ \t]/) - 1  # count of leading whitespace
    has_assign = /^[^#]*=/
  }
  $1 == "def" && !in_def { in_def = indent; next }
  indent > in_def && has_assign { print "not global:", $0; next }
  indent <= in_def { in_def = 0 }
  has_assign { print "possibly global:", $0 }
' file.py
```

This attempts to parse the python code, taking advantage of the language's mandatory indentation to keep track of when you're in a function definition.  The five `pattern {action}` pairs are:

1. No fields (blank line):
   Skip to next line
2. (Match any other line):
   Set `indent` to the number of leading spaces and tabs before the first
   Set `has_assign` to whether there is a variable assignment (a `=` exists before any `#`)
3. The first field is "def" and we're not already tracking a function:
   Keep track of the current indentation level using `ind_def` and stop matching for this line
4. We're indented enough to be in a function and we have a assignment:
   Report the non-global variable assignment
5. The indentation level is not more than the last function:
   We're not in a function any more, set the function indentation level back to zero
6. We have a variable assignment (and no `next` has been triggered yet):
   Report the possibly-global variable assignment

Note, I'm not sure all versions of `awk` understand `\t` so you might need a literal tab in its place. You can enter that on the command line as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

---

[image: ⚠] I still do not think a home-made python parser is a good idea.  If you really are parsing valid (and known-safe) python code, [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160744/detect-all-global-variables-within-a-python-function) has answers that actually *load* the code, which would of course be definitive.  If you're dealing with potentially unsafe code, or python-like code, and/or you lack a python interpreter on the system you're using, my solution might be useful for quick code vetting.