# Python `doctest` with ANSI escapes

Tags: python, doctest, ansi-escape

I have some code for which I have some doctest, e.g.

```py
def foo(x):
    """
    Examples:
        >>> s = foo()
        >>> print(repr(s))
        '\x1b[0;35mfoo\x1b[0m \x1b[0;36mbar\x1b[0m'
        >>> print(s)
        foo bar
    """
    return '\u001b[0;35mfoo\u001b[0m \u001b[0;36mbar\u001b[0m'
```

Of course, in a ANSI-escape capable terminal, the last `print()` is actually colored.

However, if I run `doctest` here, I will get a failing test.
How could I solve this?

I was hoping either to have a way of inserting ANSI escapes or, preferably, a doctest directive for ignoring them, but I could not find any information on this in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/doctest.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A silly workaround to this is to use a in-code comparison instead of relying on doctests comparisons, e.g.:

```
def foo(x):
    """
    Examples:
        >>> s = foo()
        >>> print(repr(s))
        '\x1b[0;35mfoo\x1b[0m \x1b[0;36mbar\x1b[0m'
        >>> print(s == '\x1b[0;35mfoo\x1b[0m \x1b[0;36mbar\x1b[0m')
        True
    """
    return '\u001b[0;35mfoo\u001b[0m \u001b[0;36mbar\u001b[0m'
```

---

Another possibility would be to [filter out ANSI escapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python) either right inside `print()`:

```
import re


def remove_ansi_escapes(text):
    ansi_escape = re.compile(r'(\x9B|\x1B\[)[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')
    return ansi_escape.sub('', text)


def foo(x):
    """
    Examples:
        >>> s = foo()
        >>> print(repr(s))
        '\x1b[0;35mfoo\x1b[0m \x1b[0;36mbar\x1b[0m'
        >>> print(remove_ansi_escapes(s))
        foo bar
    """
    return '\u001b[0;35mfoo\u001b[0m \u001b[0;36mbar\u001b[0m'
```

or by [capturing `STDOUT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136611/capture-stdout-from-a-script-in-python) if the printing is happening deeper in the code:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io


def foo(x):
    """
    Examples:
        >>> buffer = io.StringIO()
        >>> with redirect_stdout(buffer):
        ...     foo()
        >>> print(remove_ansi_escapes(buffer.getvalue()))
        foo bar
    """
    s = '\u001b[0;35mfoo\u001b[0m \u001b[0;36mbar\u001b[0m'
    print(s)
```