# How to read a line in the terminal with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, terminal

I'm trying to get a already written line in python 3, but I haven't found any function that can read a line from the terminal. It should work something like sys.stdout.read(), or sys.stdout.readline() but this function just throws an error.

Comment: What do you mean by *read a line from the terminal*? Run the program with sys arguments? input something to the program? read from the terminal's history? Please refer to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). In this question it is both unclear what you are asking and sounds too broad and is likely to get closed if you don't [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57145550/edit) it

Comment: I don't get what's unclear about this question.

Comment: I meant reading from the same place that print() writes to. sys.stdout doesn't have a read function.

Comment: you mean [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)? And sorry, maybe it's just me, but that question is very unclear... could be interpreted in many ways

Comment: No, input() reads user input, but I want to get text that's already been written before the function gets called.

Comment: There you have it. Quick google search

Comment: Sorry, that's it, I just couldn't find it. Thanks for finding.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to read from the user/a pipe, then simply use `input`.

However, from your comments it seems like you want to be able to read from what *has already been printed*.

To do this, you have a few options. If you don't actually want it to display on the terminal, and you only care about certain part of the output, then you can use [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html?highlight=contextlib#contextlib.redirect_stdout) and [`contextlib.redirect_stderr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html?highlight=contextlib#contextlib.redirect_stderr). You can combine this with [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) to capture the output of your application to a string. This has been discussed in the question [Capture stdout from a script in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136611/capture-stdout-from-a-script-in-python)

However, if you want to have something which provides you both a means of *printing to the terminal* and *giving you the lines*, then you will need to implement your own type which inherits from [`io.TextIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) or uses [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper).

Comment: thanks, that's pretty much excactly what I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
name = input("Enter a name: ")
print(name)
```

Comment: No, that would read user input, not terminal output.