# How to convert a for loop output into a simple variable?

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, output

I will Show you a simple demonstration of what I want to accomplish:

```
import numpy as np
word = input("Enter a word : "+ ' ')
pxlength = (len(word))
word= " ".join(word)
m = (np.str_(word))
for g in range(5):
     print(m)
```

if I Enter my name- Eitan it will print:

```
e i t a n
e i t a n
e i t a n
e i t a n
e i t a n
```

The thing that I want is a variable that represent the output,we will call him e, im trying to get to this: `print(e)`
and it will print:

```
    e i t a n
    e i t a n
    e i t a n
    e i t a n
    e i t a n
```

I tried to look for this in so much places but I probably dont know how and what exactly to search.. I know that this is a very silly qu but I really need help, tnx.

Comment: I don't understand the issue, is it the missing indentation?

Comment: You don't need that `m = (np.str_(word))`. Anyway, if you just want some white space in front of the string then just do `e = '    ' + word`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that

```
e = f'{word}\n' * 5
print(e)
```

Comment: tnx! I will try it and let you know if it helped me in the actual code

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is more complicated than it seems and probably means the problem itself is flawed - you shouldn't need to use print output further in your code.
That being said, it is possible to achieve by capturing stdout and stderr, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40417352/9296093

Comment: yeah I taught it was wayyyy easier ... ty for the link I would definitely try to understand and use it.

Comment: I'd say don't try to use it. Try to write your program in such a way that you don't need to do such weird things.

Comment: Simplest solution: Instead of printing in each iteration of a loop, create a variable that add your word to on each execution. After the loop is finished, you print everything at once and then also return the string as value.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
word = input("Enter a word : "+ ' ')
word_sep = ' '.join(word)
e = '\n'.join([word_sep]*5)
print(e)
```